# torrent file contain the collection of hash number for data packets?

Tags: bittorrent

I know that torrent file contain the data about the tracker and the hash number of that torrent

but my question is:

these torrent files also contain the hash number of all data packets regarding that torrent or not? 
(these torrent file have the collection of hash numbers for each packet?)

and how the these information are structured in torrent file?

Comment: Torrent files do not contain _infohash_ (top-level hash) explicitly. Infohashes are computed by client software by hashing so-called _infodict_ part of torrent file. But, yes, _infodict_ does include _hash list_ (the _pieces_ field of info dictionary) which denotes sha1 hash of each _piece_ (not packet): "pieces maps to a string whose length is a multiple of 20. It is to be subdivided into strings of length 20, each of which is the SHA1 hash of the piece at the corresponding index." Source: [bep3](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#info-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

.torrent files are bencoded, which is a simple encoding described in [BEP3](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#bencoding).

Here's a simplified example torrent:

```
{
'announce': 'http://bt1.archive.org:6969/announce',
'created by': 'ia_make_torrent',
'creation date': 1373568576,
'info': {
  'files': [
    { 'length': 12355245, 'path': [ 'Commodore_Amiga_TOSEC_2012_04_10.txt' ], },
    { 'length': 33979699024, 'path': [ 'Commodore_Amiga_TOSEC_2012_04_10.zip' ], },
    { 'length': 2821, 'path': [ 'Commodore_Amiga_TOSEC_2012_04_10_meta.xml' ], },
    { 'length': 378737, 'path': [ 'amiga_1000_by_macpengin.jpg' ], },
    { 'length': 4877, 'path': [ 'amiga_1000_by_macpengin_thumb.jpg' ], },
    ],
  'name': 'Commodore_Amiga_TOSEC_2012_04_10',
  'piece length': 4194304,
  'pieces': '9834f2b6e0b8d9071f2d2db...776f9c910b6622f234872e8'
  },
'locale': 'en',
'title': 'Commodore_Amiga_TOSEC_2012_04_10',
}
```

The pieces field was shortened. It contains all sha-1 hashes of the pieces, concatenated (it's in binary form, but represented as here for printability). A piece is not directly a packet.

Typically a packet would refer to an IP packet (of around 1400 bytes). On top of IP you have either TCP or uTP as the transport protocol. On top of that, you have the BitTorrent protocol which only exchanges blocks (sometimes called chunks). A block is 16 kiB. A piece is typically an even multiple of 16, and even more likely an even power of 2. So, you download a number of blocks first, concatenate them to form a piece, then verify the SHA-1 hash of that piece.